# SwiftUI PassthroughSubject not working when .send() is called from closure

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm currently having problems when trying to send an event signal with a PassthroughSubject var from a view that is using a closure with a confirm button.

To be in context, I've built 2 views: SavedRewardsView and WishListItemCard. The WishListItemCard is the one who is emitting events with PassthroughSubject and SavedRewardsView is receiving them with the .onReceive property.

So far so good, I've managed to emit and capture an event on WishListItemCard, that implements a counter and updates the UI in WishListItemCard and sends the event to SavedRewardsView to update it's UI too.

*Sending event on WishListItemCard: *

```
@State var redeemCount = 0

let didChange = PassthroughSubject<WishlistItemCounter, Never>()

VStack {
...
}
.onChange(of: self.redeemCount) { newCount in
            
            self.pointsCost = newCount * (self.rewardData.points ?? 0)
            let wic = WishlistItemCounter(rewardId: self.rewardData.id ?? 0, quantity: newCount, total: self.pointsCost)
            self.didChange.send(wic)
        }
```

*Capturing the event on SavedRewardsView: *

```
let wishlistItemCard = WishlistItemCard()

wishlistItemCard.onReceive(wishlistItemCard.didChange) { newWishlistItemCounter in
            print("wishlistItemCard.didChange")
}
```

**The problem** is on another event that needs to be sent also from WishListItemCard. The expected feature is that the user should be able to delete the item from the wishlist based a confirmation message and since this is a view called from SavedRewardsView, the data needs to be reloaded so the deleted item doesn't appear anymore on the list. So, in the action of the delete button there is a call for a custom alert that expects a title and 2 actions: one for a confirm action and the other one for a cancel action. I'm sending the event within the confirm action:

*Sending the event on SavedRewardsView: *

```
let didDeleteReward = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()

Button(action: {

            let confirmDeleteButton = CustomAlertButton(title: "Confirm", action: {
                        self.myAppManager.hideAlert()
                        self.didDeleteReward.send(true)
            }

            let cancelButton = CustomAlertButton(title: "Cancel", action: {
                        self.myAppManager.hideAlert()
            }

            self.myAppManager.showAlert(
                        message: "Delete item?",
                        dismissButton: cancelDeleteButton,
                        primaryButton: confirmDeleteButton
                    )

},
label: {
            Image("TrashIcon")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
})
```

And trying to receive the event on SavedRewardsView, but the event is not captured here:

```
let wishlistItemCard = WishlistItemCard()

wishlistItemCard
.onReceive(wishlistItemCard.didChange) { newWishlistItemCounter in
            print("wishlistItemCard.didDeleteReward")
            Task {
                await self.reloadData()
            }
}
```

Here's is what I've tried:

1. Use a @State var and attach it to .onReceive and send the event, but the event is not captured on SavedRewardsView.
2. Use CurrentValueSubject but the value itself gets updated all the time, becoming an infinite update loop.
3. Placed *self.didDeleteReward.send(true)* directly on the button's action with no confirmation message, the event is captured on SavedRewardsView but it's not the expected behaviour cause it needs confirmation.

Can you please guys help me out, I'm literally ran out of ideas.

*NOTE: the myAppManager var is a ObservableObject thats the source of truth of my application and is hierarchically passed down to the views with .environmentObject from the first view extending App.*

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI already has passthrough subjects built-in (although it's called dependency tracking or change detection) so you don't need to recreate that yourself, just do:

```
struct SavedRewardsView: View {
    @State var redeemCount = 0

    // When redeemCount's getter is called in body, SwiftUI sets up subjects to monitor the value and when the setter is called, SwiftUI will call body again to get all the new child Views.
    var body: some View {
       ...

       SavedRewardsView(redeemCount: redeemCount)
       ...
    }
}

// Although this will be init many times, body will only be called when required.
struct SavedRewardsView: View {

    // SwiftUI will monitor the value of this let
    let redeemCount: Int

    var body: some View {
        // SwiftUI will monitor the value of redeemCount and body will be called when it changes
    }
}
```

Think of `body` like the `didChange` func for all the `let`s and `@State var`s declared in the `View`.

Comment: Thank you @malhal, I've also tried both `@State` (on the parent view) and `@Binding` (on the child view). This works pretty well as you said, but the problem I'm facing is that when the @Binding var is changed from a closure, the value gets updated on the child view but it doesn't updates the parent view. _Note: the closure is running an animation of 0.5s and the action (updating the `@Binding` var or performing `send()`) is performed 0.5s later using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`._

Comment: `@Binding var` is only for when you need write-access. I believe in your case you only need read access so it should just be a `let`. However the problem you experience is very common and its because you might not be calling the state getter in the parent view. To get the parent view to update you need to call the state getter somewhere inside body, or you can add it to a closures capture list.